# Задать сменить имя input кнопки выбора файла в форме

Tags: html, css, html5, input, html-form

Обычная форма выбора файла для згрузки:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/fu.php" method="POST">
<input name="userfile" accept="image/*" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value=" Send ">
</form>
```

На кн выбора написано "Выберите файл".

[image: форма выбора файла]

Как изменить этот текст стандартными способами (если таковые имеются)? Или как-то по другому нужно решать эту проблему (сделать картинку формой и др..)?
Но хочу без дополнительных прибамбасов изменить текст.

Вопрос снят(?) Решение тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file , но я его еще не проверял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено:Скопировал решение отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file , и заключил  в нужный тег.

В css пишем:

```
#btn {
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #161;
    width: 70px;
    height: 19px;
}
```

И форма:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/fu.php" method="POST">
<div id="btn">
<label for="files">Мой текст</label>
</div>
<input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" name="userfile" accept="image/*" type="file">
<input type="submit" value=" Send ">
</form>
```

Только мне не хватает пробела перед "Мой текст" - (решил!: padding-left: 5px; в css). И саму кнопку чуть вниз нужно сдвинуть, но это уже не столь важно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#btn {
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #161;
    width: 70px;
    height: 19px;
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/fu.php" method="POST">
<div id="btn">
<label for="files">Мой текст</label>
</div>
<input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" name="userfile" accept="image/*" type="file">
<input type="submit" value=" Send ">
</form>
```